# Automating Git release workflow with CI job

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, gitlab, devops

I have the following development setup:

- Git projects hosted on a self hosted GitLab
- GitLab CI runs jobs on certain branches every time I push (build, test, and lint code, for example)

So far, so good. But now, I want to automated certain git tasks. For example, suppose the hypothetical following release strategy for my minor releases:

- On dev branch, remove the -SNAPSHOT version from the version file (`package.json`, `pom.xml`... depends on the project), then commit
- Merge dev into master and tag the merge commit `vX.Y.Z`
- On dev, bump the minor version and append it with `-SNAPSHOT`, then commit
- Trigger a deploy script (or have a deploy CI job that gets triggered in GitLab CI whenever a vX.Y.Z tag is pushed to master)

How would I integrate this release script into my CI setup ?

I know that Jenkins can do such things, and I happen to have a docker instance of it running. I also thought I could define a script in GitLab CI that does the job and pushes the changes to the Git repo using a deploy key.

The important thing I want to achieve is to have versions managed automatically. For that reason, I currently have a node script that taks as input the current -SNAPSHOT version and outputs the release version and next development SNAPSHOT version, computed automatically. I know `npm` and `maven` have commands like `nom version patch minor` but I want to manage version bumping myself (and not delegate it to the dependency manager).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so here is how I ended up doing it:

1. I created a command-line-tool for getting/setting the version of a project, depending on its type, which I provide as a command line argument. It helps my tool find out where to get / set the version (`package.json` for a project of type `NPM`, `pom.xml` for `MAVEN`, etc.
2. I created a bash script that performs my desired release workflow. The script uses the command-line tool I created to get/set the project version. My Jenkins release job is a parametrized job that takes as input the project type, the repository URL, and the repository credentials. It clones, makes changes and pushes the changes to Gitlab. Doing this, I can setup a simple job for each of my projects, that triggers the generic release job using the [parametrized trigger plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin). This job can optionally trigger another job that deploys to a test environment.
3. The release job needs an additional parameter to know which type of version bump it must do, whether it is null (meaning "do a pre-release", minor, or major.